# .appendchild is not a function - in a "for in" loop

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

The console throws an error: `P[i].appendChild is not a function`. 
The error does not appear if I use the simple "for loop" `for( var i=0 ; i<P.length ; ++i )` - instead of the "for-in loop"

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="parent"></div>
  <div class="parent"></div>
  <div class="parent"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var P = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
for (var i in P){
  var Child = document.createElement("div");
  Child.class = "child";
  P[i].appendChild(Child);
}
```

Why I can't use "for-in" and ".appendChild()" at the same time?

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` for iterating through numeric indexes. Use a `for` loop and an index variable.

Comment: Also creating a bunch of elements with the same "id" value is wrong too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`getElementsByClassName` does not return an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), so `P` is an object, not an array. Specifically, it is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) with properties other than just nodes, so those properties do not have the method.

You can see that in the example below.

```js
var P = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
for (var i in P){
  var output = document.createElement('div');
  
  output.innerHTML = "Checking for appendChild on property '" + i + "' on the collection: " + typeof P[i].appendChild;
  document.body.appendChild(output);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="parent"></div>
  <div class="parent"></div>
  <div class="parent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: in this case it should be an array of objects! (`P=document.getElementsByClassName`)

Comment: @Jeff No, `getElementsByClassName` does not return an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName.